# Under what conditions differentiation inside an improper integral holds?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, complex-integration, bessel-functions

Consider the following identity
$$
\int_0^\infty \sin (\rho q) \, J_1 (r q) \, \mathrm{d}q = \frac{\rho}{r(r^2-\rho^2)^{1/2}} \, , 
$$
where $J_1$ denotes Bessel function of the first kind of order 1.
This identity can easily be checked using computer algebra software such as Maple.
By differentiating both members by the parameter $\rho$ and interchanging the order of differentiation and integration we readily obtain
$$
\int_0^\infty q \cos (\rho q) \, J_1 (r q) \, \mathrm{d}q = \frac{r}{(r^2-\rho^2)^{3/2}} \, .
$$

I would like to know whether performing such order interchange is appropriate. Or what conditions should be satisfied in order to proceed that way. Any hints / ideas would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

r

Comment: Should the $r$ in numerator and denominator of the second equation cancel?

Comment: @Neal Yes indeed. There is no $r$ in the denominator. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Check [this link](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf) or [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf). They contains some results about differentiating under improper integrals.

Comment: @Masacroso thanks for the link. I will have a read on it.